# Java 8 Streams : Add validation to avoid duplicate keys

Tags: java-8, java-stream

The following code throws `Exception` when it tries to add a duplicate id. How can I modify the code to avoid duplicates?

```
return Optional.ofNullable(list)
   .isPresent() ? (list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(ViewObject::getId, viewObject -> viewObject))) : new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Please refer this https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(list) .isPresent()` is an obfuscated way to check for `list != null`. If you want to avoid using a plain operator at all costs, use `return Objects.requireNonNullElse​( list, Collections.emptyList()) .stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(ViewObject::getId, viewObject -> viewObject));`

Answer (score 2):

There is an [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) of `toMap` which allows to specify `mergeFunction`:

```
Collectors.toMap(ViewObject::getId,
    viewObject -> viewObject,
    (a, b) -> a // Resolve the duplicates here
)
```

Additionally, `Optional.ofNullable(list).isPresent()` seems to be unnecessary. You can completely skip it by initializing the list if it is `null`. `Optional`s should be used in the method signature and not inside the method body.